# c# How to prevent output from a TransformManyBlock being discarded when the linked BufferBlock's bounded capacity is less than the output TPL

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dataflow

Lets say that the output from the TransformManyBlock is 1000 Items but the linked BufferBlock's bounded capacity is 500.

How would you prevent the other 500 items from being discarded and instead have the TransformManyBlocks function be blocked until capacity becomes available in the BufferBlock.

```
var transformBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dataFlowBlockOptions.TransformBlockMaxDop,
            BoundedCapacity = dataFlowBlockOptions.TransformBlockBoundedCapacity,
            EnsureOrdered = dataFlowBlockOptions.EnsureOrdered
        };

        var transform = new TransformManyBlock<TIn, TOut>(transformBody, transformBlockOptions);

        var actionBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dataFlowBlockOptions.ActionBlockMaxDop,
            BoundedCapacity = dataFlowBlockOptions.ActionBlockBoundedCapicity
        };

        var action = new ActionBlock<TOut>(actionBody, actionBlockOptions);

        //Enables propegation of commands and exceptions to and from linked blocks;
        var dataflowLinkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = false };

        var buffer = new BufferBlock<TOut>();

        //Only forward responses that aren't null to the ActionBlock
        if (dataFlowBlockOptions.SetNullPredicate)
        {
            transform.LinkTo(buffer, dataflowLinkOptions, p => p != null);

            //Null responses need to be consumed by something otherwise it causes a deadlock
            transform.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<TOut>());
        }
        else
        {
            transform.LinkTo(buffer, dataflowLinkOptions);
        }

        buffer.LinkTo(action, dataflowLinkOptions);

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            await transform.SendAsync(item, dataFlowBlockOptions.CancellationToken);
        }

        transform.Complete();
        await transform.Completion;

        buffer.Complete();
        await buffer.Completion;

        action.Complete();
        await action.Completion;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I found that when the BufferBlocks capacity was reached, data was flowing into the NullTargetBlock and messages were being discarded.